# Nested Where clause can access global variable but inner join can't

Tags: mysql, join

The below example is just a demonstration of the problem i am facing.

I have two tables A & B on which i want to query. There schemas are as below

```
create table A
(
    id int,
    B_id int, 
    D_id int,
    created date
);


create table B
(
    id int,
    C_id int
);
```

Table A can have multiple rows for a given B_id.

I insert test data as below :

```
insert into A(id, B_id, D_id, created) values(2, 1, 0, now());
insert into A(id, B_id, D_id, created) values(3, 1, 0, now());
```

Now, I want to fetch the newest(whose created is having the highest value) rows in A which have B_id = 1

Now, the problem :

I tried below double inner join which did not work

```
select * from A 
    inner join B on A.B_id = B.id
    inner join ( select * from A  where A.B_id = B.id order by created desc limit 1) as A1 on A.id = A1.id
    and A.B_id = 1;
```

this fails with the error "Unknown column 'B.id' in 'where clause'"

However if i replace the second inner join with a where clause as below, it works :

```
select * from A 
    inner join B on A.B_id = B.id
    and A.id =  ( select id from A  where A.B_id = B.id order by created desc limit 1) 
    and A.B_id = 1;
```

Why can where clause access the B.id in global scope but inner join can't??

Answer (score 1):

This is a good point. It took me a while to get my head around. First of all I personally would not call it "global" scope. But I've got your point :)

Here is how I understand it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**First query**: I changed your query `B.id` to `1`, so I can run the query correctly. I changed it to the following:

```
select * from A 
    inner join B on A.B_id = B.id
    inner join ( select * from A  where A.B_id = 1 order by created desc limit 1) as A1 on A.id = A1.id
    and A.B_id = 1;
```

After I changed it, I did `explain select ...` to see how it work. Here is what I've got.

```
id   select_type    table         type     possible_keys     key     key_len     ref     rows     Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    PRIMARY        <derived2>    system   null              null    null        null    1        null
1    PRIMARY        B             ALL      null              null    null        null    1        Using where
1    PRIMARY        A             ALL      null              null    null        null    4        Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2    DERIVED        A             ALL      null              null    null        null    4        Using where; Using filesort
```

It seems that your subquery `select * from A  where A.B_id = 1 order by created desc limit 1` is executed during or before `INNER JOIN`. `B.id` is not yet available since `INNER JOIN` hasn't been done yet.

**Second query**: I did the same `explain select ...`

```
id   select_type        table     type  possible_keys     key     key_len     ref     rows     Extra
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    PRIMARY            B         ALL   null              null    null        null    1        Using where
1    PRIMARY            A         ALL   null              null    null        null    4        Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY A         ALL   null              null    null        null    4        Using where; Using filesort
```

As you can see, your subquery is executed after `INNER JOIN`. Therefore `B.id` is available.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation & use of explain select(which i just got to learn :) , however i would love to know if there's a reason for this. Will wait to see if someone else can reply